# how to change the default version of node through lastest NVM.

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am using latest nvm 0.24.1 ..

I install 3 node. 0.8, 0.10 and latest 0.12. I first make 0.10 as default node using aliast

```
 nvm alias default 0.10
```

Now, I want to change the 0.10 to 0.12 as default. Will anybody tell, how can I change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could use more aliases. check out the link [managing multiple node version](http://codetheory.in/using-node-version-manager-nvm-to-manage-multiple-node-js-versions/)

nvm alias  
 Set node v0.8.22 to use by default

```
nvm alias default 0.8.22
```

Basically nvm alias is used to set a name pointing to a particular node version.

More aliases?

```
$ nvm alias ten 0.10.0
```

ten -> 0.10.0 (-> v0.10.0)

```
$ nvm alias
```

default -> 0.8.22 (-> v0.8.22)

ten -> 0.10.0 (-> v0.10.0)

```
$ nvm use ten
```

Now using node v0.10.0

Comment: After making the last command " nvm use ten " . If I closed the terminal and open it. Will it be default..